# Stale value of Shared variable

Tags: java, multithreading

While reading Concurrency in practice I read that:

> `NoVisibility` demonstrated one of the ways that insufficiently
> synchronized programs can cause surprising results: stale data. When the
> reader thread examines `ready`, it may see an out of date value. Unless
> synchronization is used every time a variable is accessed, it is
> possible to see a stale value for that variable. Worse, staleness is
> not all or nothing: a thread can see an up-to-date value of one variable
> but a stale value of another variable that was written first.

```
public class NoVisibility {
    private static boolean ready;
    private static int number;

    private static class ReaderThread extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            while (!ready)
                Thread.yield();
            System.out.println(number);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ReaderThread().start();
        number = 42;
        ready = true;
    }
}
```

I am not getting meaning of stale. Both threads are sharing the same reference, how can a value modified by one be or not be visible to other thread?

Comment: It might be outdated, the changes won't be visible.

Comment: @NarendraPathai How's that a duplicate?

Comment: @MarounMaroun it provided some background, retracting the vote.

Comment: But both threads are acting on same variable space. Do it is like this that after reading the value , one thread will keep it in its cache and keep referring it . In this scenario , how will the value in its cache will get modify??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's saying that in `main` the intention is to set `number=42` and `ready=true` at the same time, but since they were called in this particular order there is a race condition with your `ReaderThread` where it could (probably will) print out the number even though we really don't want it to.

They would like you to synchronize those 2 variables to be set together.

Comment: This does answer the question; any readers of the section in the book coming through here however will notice that the book goes on to say: "NoVisibility could loop forever because the value of ready might never become visible to the reader thread.", which other explanations that involve the memory model of the JVM are needed for.

Answer (score 7):

> Each thread has its *own stack*, and so its own copy of variables it can
>   access. When the thread is created, it copies the value of all
>   accessible variables in its own memory. The volatile keyword is used
>   to say to the jvm "***Warning, this variable may be modified in an other
>   Thread***". Without this keyword the JVM is free to make some
>   optimizations, like ***never refreshing*** those local copies in some
>   threads. The volatile force the thread to update the original variable
>   for each variable.

Source [DZone](http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-volatile-keyword-0)

***Hardware Implementation***

This happens due to the processor optimizations that are done for fast access of variables. When the variable is kept in the cache then it is much faster to access than going to memory everytime. So for flushing the cache you need to say `volatile` go and flush the cache and rebuild it as this variable is being modified in other thread.

The caching of `static` variables is also done, they too are a eligible for caching due to same reason *fast access*. So yes you need `volatile` for `static` variables too.

See also:

[What does volatile do?](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#volatile)

Comment: But both are static variable , then how come it is possible , that threads are maintaining them in their local stack and modified value is not reflected to other thread?

Comment: If I am not wrong, Yes that is true for static variables too, as static variables exist in Java and processor does not know about them. So for processor its just a place in memory that is going to be edited by several threads.

Comment: But only one copy of that variable will be there , how come different thread will have their own copy?

Comment: Processor caching is hardware detail and is unrelated to Java. Yes for us there is only one instance but in memory that can be copied for caching purposes.

Answer (score 7):

It's not Java specific issue. Processors have caches. Without synchronization processor 1 can read a value into its cache from memory, modify it in its cache but never flush it, then processor 2 reads stale value from memory

Comment: Is it is true for static variables also?

Comment: It make no difference static or not as soon as data is shared between different threads. Only local variables do not have this problem because they cannot be not shared.

Comment: I'm not sure this is true, at least for most CPUs. MESI protocol is supposed to handle coherence issues related to CPU caches.

Answer (score 3):

This issue is related to `memory visibility` issue of Multithreading.

If you want to read/get value of an object which can be modified by multiple threds; then you need to be careful. Let's take a sample example to stress the point :

```
public class XYZ{
   private String state;

   public synchronized setState(..){
      //set state
   } 
   public String getState(){
      return state;
   }
```

}

Above example doesn't synchronize the getter method which returns the state. So you might get the stale data **(even if its static)**

> Only way to get latest data is either you syncronize the get method or declare state as volatile.