# Setting variable through protected function - lost reference

Tags: java, android, variables

#### Update 2017 (in progress...)

In summary the situation now looks like this.
I click instance of `B` (android fragment) and expect `onContextItemSelected` of that instance to be to be called. The `onContextItemSelected` is called indeed but it turns out that this method of instance of class `C`.

I've been asked to show the project. After looking at this code after about 2 years I decided I should do a little more clarification on it first as it not event commented above maybe 5%. I don't think I would be able to do much more today buy I've draw some overview on whole project so you know where to look at. It's not fully completed and may contain some mistakes but more less this is how it look like:

[image]

I will try to post clear steps on how to reproduce it tomorrow. But if you want to look at it anyway I'm including the files already [here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/do8jdm45w96wgou/androidQustion.rar)

`A` is `BaseCustomFragment`

`B` and `C` are classes which extends it.

#### Old

I've got something like this:

```
public class A extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener, OnItemLongClickListener{
    protected D loc;

    protected void setContext(D l){
        Log.d("A", "setContext :" + String.valueOf(l));
        loc = l;
        Log.d("A", "setContext2 :" + String.valueOf(loc));
    }

    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Log.d("A", "itemSelected :" + String.valueOf(loc));
    }
}
```

and

```
public class B extends A{

    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> pr, View view,int p, long id) {
        D d = (D) pr.getItemAtPosition(p);
        Log.d("B", "longClick :" + String.valueOf(d));
        setContext(d);
        return false;
    }
}
```

and log look like this:

> B    longClick :data
>
> A    setContext :data
>
> A    setContext2 :data
>
> A    itemSelected :null

I'm not touching `loc` or `setContex` anywhere else. I have completely no idea what is going on. How it is possible?

I'm setting `A` class as `ListView` listener. I'm using this fragment in `ViewPager`. `onItemSelected` is called right after the `setContext`.
Don't know what to say more about this.

### Edit:

Declate as volatile  didn't fix it but...
Even more wierd stuff - in class `A` I've got:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    lv = (ListView) inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, container, false);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    //this.registerForContextMenu(lv);
    return lv;
}
```

I also added to class `B` for now:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    this.registerForContextMenu(lv);
    return lv;
}
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    //Never called!
    Log.d("Loc", "selected :" + name);
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

Where the magic happens is that I have also class `C`which is basically the same as `B` only that i didn't override those extra methods above:

```
public class C extends A {      
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        ...
    }   
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
        ...
    }       
}
```

And the log shows:

> B    longClick :data - from instance of `B`
>
> A    setContext :data - from instance of `B`
>
> A    setContext2 :data - from instance of `B`
>
> A    itemSelected :null - from instance of `C`!!!

How about that? I'm calling `registerForContext` only in class `B` Any ideas?

Comment: i call `registerForContextMenu` on class `A` passing `ListView`. Should I include it in question?

Comment: can you post a basic project?

Comment: You might find some or all of the following helpful. 1) You can have more than one instance of a class. Verify whether loc is getting cleared, or is just still the initial null value in a different instance. 2) Use a debugger to see verify which instances you're working with, and when/whether loc is getting cleared. 3) Avoid protected variables to ensure that no other class can modify loc. Make loc private.

Comment: @azizbekian Well I could post entire project if you want - it's kind of dropped. But it's quite a few files to analyze and I don't know how to strip it any better then it's done in question.

Comment: @AndyThomas See last quote in question - it looks like i call method of instance of `B` but somehow `itemSelected` is called from another instance of class even different class `C`! Both `B` and `C` extends `A`.

Comment: @PawełAudionysos - So everything that's happening with your B instance is irrelevant to your C instance. The member variables in A are not shared between different instances. Your log never shows you calling C.setContext(). From your sample code, that's the only way `loc` gets set. Until then, it's null by default.

Comment: Sorry for not been clear. I doN'T expect to get any data from `C`. I expect `A itemSelected :data from instance of B`  instead of `A itemSelected :null - from instance of C`

Comment: Kindly post the full code of class A, B, C and D if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

**What's going wrong?**

You use `ViewPager` in combination with `FragmentPagerAdapter`. What is an important implementation deatil of this combination is that you have several `Fragment`s attached to the `Activity`. This is required for `ViewPager` to work as it need at least next and previous `Fragment`s with their `View`s to be ready for swapping.

What's wrong is that you don't take this behavior of `ViewPager` into account when you dispatch your `MenuItem`s using only title. This is in general a horrible idea and this is just on of examples why it is wrong. When context menu is shown and user selects some item, first `MainActivity` has a chance to handle it, then the event goes to the `FragmentManager` which dispatches the event to ***all*** attached `Fragment`s (because there is no other reasonable choice if you think about it). Thus each of your `Fragment`s receives `onMenuItemSelected` call and tries to handle it as `MenuItem` titles are the same. And of course you have an exception because for other `Fragment`s "context" of currently selected item is not set.

**How to fix it?**

Obviously don't use just title to dispatch event for your `MenuItem`s. You can actually generate unique `groupId` or `itemId` for each `Fragment`. But I prefer more OOP-like way. First get rid of all your original context-menu management code (`menus`, `mpos`, `setMenu`, `addMenuItem`, `removeItemMenu`, `onMenuItemSelected`, etc.) and replace them with something like this

```java
public class BaseCustomFragment extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener, OnItemLongClickListener
{

    private List<MenuItemAction> menus = new ArrayList<MenuItemAction>();

    // base class for all actions for context-menu in BaseCustomFragment 
    abstract class MenuItemAction implements MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener
    {
        private final String title;

        public MenuItemAction(String title)
        {
            this.title = title;
        }

        public String getTitle()
        {
            return title;
        }

        public final boolean isVisible()
        {
            return isVisibleImpl(conCon, locCon);
        }

        @Override
        public final boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item)
        {
            AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
            Log.d("MenuItem", "menu item '" + title + "' for #" + info.position + " of  " + BaseCustomFragment.this.getClass().getSimpleName());
            handleActionImpl(conCon, locCon);
            return true;
        }

        protected final void startActivity(Uri uri)
        {
            startActivity(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        }

        protected final void startActivity(String action, Uri uri)
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(action, uri));
        }

        protected final void startActivity(Class<? extends Activity> activityClass)
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), activityClass));
        }

        protected final void startActivity(Intent intent)
        {
            getActivity().startActivity(intent);
        }

        protected abstract boolean isVisibleImpl(Customer conCon, Localization locCon);

        protected abstract void handleActionImpl(Customer conCon, Localization locCon);

    }

    protected void setContext(Customer c, Localization l)
    {
        Log.d("BaseFrag", "setContext class:" + String.valueOf(this.getClass()));
        Log.d("BaseFrag", "setContext :" + String.valueOf(l));
        conCon = c;
        locCon = l;
        Log.d("BaseFrag", "setContext2 :" + String.valueOf(locCon));
        updateContextMenu();
    }

    protected void setMenus(MenuItemAction... menuItems)
    {
        this.menus = Arrays.asList(menuItems);
        updateContextMenu();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo info)
    {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, info);

        for (MenuItemAction menuItemAction : menus)
        {
            if (menuItemAction.isVisible())
            {
                MenuItem menuItem = menu.add(menuItemAction.getTitle());
                menuItem.setOnMenuItemClickListener(menuItemAction);
            }
        }
    }


    private void updateContextMenu()
    {
        if (lv == null)
            return;
        boolean hasVisibleItems = false;
        for (MenuItemAction menuItemAction : menus)
        {
            if (menuItemAction.isVisible())
            {
                hasVisibleItems = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (hasVisibleItems)
        {
            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Attaching context menu for " + getClass().getSimpleName());
            this.registerForContextMenu(lv);
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Detaching context menu for " + getClass().getSimpleName());
            this.unregisterForContextMenu(lv);
        }
    }
```

Here `MenuItemAction` is a base class for all "internal" menu items that would be held by each `Fragment` independently. I call them "internal" because "real" `MenuItem`s are implementation details and you can't inherit from them so we'll create "real" ones from our "internal" ones. This transformation/creation is done inside `onCreateContextMenu`. Note that `MenuItemAction` dispatches events already providing your "context" data to where it is need. It also contains a few `startActivity` helper methods to simplify code.

Now we can add to `BaseCustomFragment` a bunch of helper methods to create your typical menu items:

```java
    protected MenuItemAction createNavigateToLocationMenuItem()
    {
        return new MenuItemAction("Navigate to location")
        {
            @Override
            protected boolean isVisibleImpl(Customer conCon, Localization locCon)
            {
                return (locCon != null);
            }

            @Override
            protected void handleActionImpl(Customer conCon, Localization locCon)
            {
                startActivity(Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" + Uri.encode(locCon.noZipString())));
            }
        };
    }

    protected MenuItemAction createCallMenuItem()
    {
        return new MenuItemAction("Call")
        {
            @Override
            protected boolean isVisibleImpl(Customer conCon, Localization locCon)
            {
                return (conCon != null) && (conCon.getPhoneNumbers().size() > 0);
            }

            @Override
            protected void handleActionImpl(Customer conCon, Localization locCon)
            {
                startActivity(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:" + Uri.encode(BaseCustomFragment.this.conCon.getPhoneNumbers().get(0).toString())));
            }
        };
    }

    protected MenuItemAction createSmsMenuItem()
    {
        return new MenuItemAction("SMS")
        {
            @Override
            protected boolean isVisibleImpl(Customer conCon, Localization locCon)
            {
                return (conCon != null) && (conCon.getPhoneNumbers().size() > 0);
            }

            @Override
            protected void handleActionImpl(Customer conCon, Localization locCon)
            {
                startActivity(Uri.parse("sms:" + Uri.encode(BaseCustomFragment.this.conCon.getPhoneNumbers().get(0).toString())));
            }
        };
    }

    protected MenuItemAction createEmailMenuItem()
    {
        return new MenuItemAction("Email")
        {
            @Override
            protected boolean isVisibleImpl(Customer conCon, Localization locCon)
            {
                return (conCon != null) && (conCon.getEmail().length() > 0);
            }

            @Override
            protected void handleActionImpl(Customer conCon, Localization locCon)
            {
                startActivity(Uri.parse("mailto:" + Uri.encode(conCon.getEmail())));
            }
        };
    }

    protected MenuItemAction createNewOrderMenuItem()
    {
        return new MenuItemAction("New Order")
        {
            @Override
            protected boolean isVisibleImpl(Customer conCon, Localization locCon)
            {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            protected void handleActionImpl(Customer conCon, Localization locCon)
            {
                startActivity(OrderActivity.class);
            }
        };
    }
```

So what's left is to use this infrastructure specific fragments such as

```java
public class CustomersFrag extends BaseCustomFragment
{
    public CustomersFrag()
    {

        ... 

        setMenus(createCallMenuItem(),
                 createSmsMenuItem(),
                 createEmailMenuItem(),
                 createNewOrderMenuItem(),
                 createNavigateToLocationMenuItem());
    }

    ... 

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        Customer c = (Customer) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        setContext(c, c.getLocalization());
        return super.onItemLongClick(parent, view, position, id);
    }
```

or

```java
public class LocalizationsFrag extends BaseCustomFragment
{
    public LocalizationsFrag()
    {

        ... 

        setMenus(
                createNavigateToLocationMenuItem(),
                createNewOrderMenuItem());
    }

    ... 

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        Localization o = (Localization) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        setContext(null, o);
        return super.onItemLongClick(parent, view, position, id);
    }
```

Notice how you have no `if`/`else` or `switch` by menu item title in your code anymore. Moreover, you don't have to do your strange `addMenuItem`/`removeMenuItem` in each `onItemLongClick` depending on data in specific fragments because:

1. Each `MenuItemAction` now has own `isVisibleImpl` and `handleActionImpl` methods
2. `setContext` calls `updateContextMenu`

All for you menu actions seems to be generic and fit into simple "context" you already have. Thus I made `MenuItemAction` just a non-static inner class that can get it's parent `Fragment` using `BaseCustomFragment.this`.  If at some point this becomes a limitation and you would like to create an action that is specific to sub subclass of `BaseCustomFragment` and you want it to use data from that fragment you just have to create menu item in the corresponding sub-class. Imagine you want to add a "Copy Order" menu item. You do something like this:

```java
public class OrdersFragment extends BaseCustomFragment
{

    ... 


    private Order currentOrder;

    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        Order o = (Order) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        currentOrder = o;
        setContext(o.getCustomer(), o.getLocalization());

        return super.onItemLongClick(parent, view, position, id);
    }

    protected MenuItemAction createNewOrderMenuItem()
    {
        return new MenuItemAction("Copy Order")
        {
            @Override
            protected boolean isVisibleImpl(Customer conCon, Localization locCon)
            {
                return (OrdersFragment.this.currentOrder != null);
            }

            @Override
            protected void handleActionImpl(Customer conCon, Localization locCon)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), OrderActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("copySrcId", OrdersFragment.this.currentOrder.getId());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        };
    }
```

and now your "Copy Order" `MenuItemAction` has access to `currentOrder` defined inside `OrdersFragment`.

**Side Notes**

Looking at your code I've noticed a few more things that I believe worth mentioning:

- Using integer type for phone number is a bad idea. Phone numbers might contain additional symbols such as "+" or "*" or "#" that will not fit into and integer-based type. Phone numbers might start with "0" and you'll loose converting to integer-based type.
- I think you should learn `java.util` package better. For example there is a `contains` method in `java.util.List` and its subclasses.
- It is not clear why you use very specific types in your declarations when you can user superclass/interface. For example, all your Model classes seem to use `java.sql.Timestamp` for date fields for no apparent reasons (do you realy need nanoseconds?). Or you use `ArrayList` everywhere although sometimes just `List` is enough
- In your `MainActivity` in `prepareTabs` you don't call       `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after you've added tabs. Actually this leads to a crash with newer support library.

Hope this helps

---

**Old answer** (and most probably irrelevant)

Add `this` to each `Log` call. I suspect that the answer is that in

> B longClick :data
>
> A setContext :data
>
> A setContext2 :data
>
> A itemSelected :null

somehow the last `Log` is done for different object that the first 3. Also is it true that the issue is not reproducible every time? If so maybe it is related to device rotation or something else triggering Activity re-creation in the middle of your event handling. So you can add log to your `onPause` and `onResume` and see if this is the case.

Comment: what you man add "Add `this` to each `Log` call"? I've already traced out `String.valueOf(this.getClass())` in log calls and the result is shown in last quote - last call is from instance of different class so it's obviously not the same instance. :)

Comment: @PawełAudionysos,  I was suggesting loggint `this` instead of `this.getClass()` so you could see somehting like `you.package.A@1234#hashCode` which would be more unique for different objects, but yes I was wrong and your updated log already says that the last line comes from different object. So me next idea would be to override `registerForContextMenu` in your class `A` and log there `this`, probably with stack trace using `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()` so then you can find out how `C` is registered there. P.S. you didn't answer if the issue is easily reproducible.

Comment: @PawełAudionysos, If the bug is reproducible and you are willing to share the code and provide clear steps to reproduce, someone will be willing to debug (most probably including me0

Comment: I believe the bug was persistent but the be honest I didn't compile it since then so I need to refresh my memory about this. I would be posting some updates today on this, trying to make question more clear and maybe I would post the code. Can yo tip me how I should post the project? It's many files and I'm generating those lists base on data from database. The code is quite generic. Easiest for me would be to post entire project but I don't want to frighten anyone with it's complexity. Also should I post it on github or pack it in archive? What you think?

Comment: @PawełAudionysos, it might be that all SO users will be frightened by your code but do you have any better alternatives now? As for putting it to the GitHub vs packing, it is mostly up to you. One thing is that I don't know whether putting it to GitHub automatically enforces it to become some sort open-source or not. Packing obviosly avoids this issue altogether. Also don't forget to provide clear "Steps to reproduce"!

Comment: @PawełAudionysos, I played with your code a bit and can't reproduce the issue. I pre-filled all tabs with some fake data. I assume that `B` is `LocalizationsFrag` and you have to do something with context menu there but it seems to work OK at the first glance. So steps to reproduce are welcome. Or do I have to change something in the code as well?

Comment: Thanks for your interest! Seriously I cannot tell you right now how to reproduce it. I probably did something as work around "for a moment" but I'm going to sleep already so if you are not very curious, just wait for more info, a should post it tomorrow.

Comment: @PawełAudionysos, I think I've found the reason of your issues. See my updated answer. Also just in case I've uploaded my current copy of your project to http://dropmefiles.com/vlXuc Note that the link will expire in a week or two. Also note that besides fixes there is some code to populate your UI with fake data. It is mostly around `populateFromLocal`

Comment: Thank you. You found the root of the problem. You are grate and bounty comes to you. However as for your concerns. 
I understand that my code is kind of unusual and you don't use to such format but despite the fact were in some cases it's basically lack of my knowledge on java or android, many aspects of my design are are done on purpose. For example I like to see line like "setMenus(new String[]{"Call", "SMS", "Email", "New Order","Navigate to location"}, null);" at the top of my class.

Comment: Because even if you have no idea what the class suppose to do you can quickly recognize that this is responsible for the menu list you see in app, simply by reading this single line (these are actual strings you see). and than if I would like to have another language later I would simply add some line like `Translator.fromCurrentDict(s);` at the top of `addItemMenu` function.

Comment: "If at some point this becomes a limitation and you would like to create an action that is specific to sub subclass of BaseCustomFragment" That was actually main reason I wrote it that way - if I want to have custom menu item all I need to do is add string to `setMenus` (+0 lines)
and add single if statement (+2 lines?) and if `onContextItemSelected` is not already overridden (+3 lines?). And that's it - in summary gives me about +5 new lines while in comparison in your example "you just have to create menu item in the corresponding sub-class." gives about  +20 which is mostly boilerplate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138444/discussion-between-pawel-audionysos-and-serggr).

Comment: @PawełAudionysos, not sure if I can persuade you but I added some comments to the chat.

Comment: I've answered. Can I set notification to main SO menu bar?

Comment: @PawełAudionysos, I believe the only way to send notification is to add a comment as I'm doing now for my round of answers (if you are not too bored already)

Comment: I'm not bored. Maybe you will as a question I didn't think about :) - check new response in chat.

Comment: @PawełAudionysos, pingback (next round of comments)

Comment: bit late you have a message.

Comment: @PawełAudionysos, added one more round

Comment: new one is shorter :)

Comment: @PawełAudionysos, just one more time

Comment: Yup. It was my pleasure to chat with you but we can spend this time more productively. Take care! :) No more message in chat.

Answer (score 1):

If your `A` object is being accessed from multiple threads (which seems likely given your event listeners), you can see problems like this (the general terminology for it is ["stale data"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20738642/stale-value-of-shared-variable)). To quickly check whether this is a threading issue, declare your member variable as `protected volatile D loc;` and see if the problem goes away (see [this resource about volatile](http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-volatile-keyword-0)). If this does indeed solve the problem, you will need to go about implementing more advanced threading protections to make sure you don't run into any more nefarious/subtle threading bugs.